# check if any is 0

Tags: php, sql

How to check with php/sql if any of fields in database that are selected in while loop is 0?

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM table'); \\check here?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array)
{
 \\or check here?
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I need to select all fields and then check if any one of them is 0.

Comment: please clarify the scenario please. What exactly is the purpose of finding out?

Comment: Any of the fields refer to id and name!  Why you want to check name is zero?

Comment: Do you actually need to _use_ the rows, whether or not there are any zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foundZero = false;
$res = mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM table');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    if (in_array(0, $row))
    {
        // This row has a zero
        $foundZero = true;
    }
}

if ($foundZero)
{
    // at least one zero in one row has been found
}
else
{
    // No zeros have been found
}
```

If `$foundZero` is true, then at least one field in one row is equal to 0. Otherwise, all fields are non-zero.

Comment: yes! that what i was looking for... at least one zero! My head if just so F Up by sitting by the pc for many hours.. tahnks!

Answer (score 0):

in the query add a where clause

```
SELECT id, name FROM table where my_field=0
```

then you not need to check every results, you get only the wanted results rows.

Comment: That's not what Im loooking for.. I need to select all fields and then check if any one of them is 0.

Comment: what fields for example you need to check ?

Comment: let's say the same name... name can be NULL with default value 0. If name is not filled its value is 0. I need to select all names and then see if any of them is 0. 'mysql_num_rows' woun't solve anything

Comment: @Zorgyo If you actually need to use the fields you selected, maybe it's worth making two queries; a database might be faster at this than PHP.

Comment: so need to do the check in the while over rows like Russell wrote, or separate to 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, check inside the while loop.  For the query may return ZERO row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE my_field=0'); \\check here?
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array)
    {
         \\or check here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to return all rows and then check for zero, add an order by clause to your query to minimize your checking.

```
SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

then

```
if ($id <= 0)
   handleIt()
else
   proceed()
```